# catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp is full Error Message when placing order

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.1.5, tiered-pricing

I have upgraded my Magento website from the version of 2.1.5 to 2.1.10. After the up-gradation, I'm getting following error message while I try to place order.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1114 The table
>   'catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp' is full, query was:
>   INSERT INTO catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp SELECT
>   sub.parent_id, sub.entity_id, sub.customer_group_id, sub.website_id,
>   sub.price, sub.tier_price FROM (SELECT e.entity_id,
>   cg.customer_group_id, cw.website_id,
>   IF(IFNULL(tas_tax_class_id.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_tax_class_id.value,
>   tad_tax_class_id.value) AS tax_class_id,
>   IFNULL((ta_price.valu…atetimeAStas_special_to_dateON
>   tas_special_to_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
>   tas_special_to_date.attribute_id = 80 AND tas_special_to_date.store_id
>   = cs.store_id INNER JOINya_catalog_product_super_linkASlON l.product_id = e.entity_id INNER JOINya_catalog_product_entityASleON
>   le.entity_id = l.parent_id WHERE (IF(IFNULL(tas_status.value_id, -1) >
>   0, tas_status.value, tad_status.value)=1)) ASsubON DUPLICATE KEY
>   UPDATEprice= VALUES(price),tier_price= VALUES(tier_price`)...

All the products have tier price basically. It was working fine before up-gradation. I'm facing this only after the up-gradation.